# What is wrong with this JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I have created simple gui application using `JFilechooser` for opening a pdf file. The gui has a browse button and a textArea to visualize the contents of the file.

I have created two classes: Gui(contains main()) and  GuiJFrame to implement the gui, handlers and listeners. I have managed to get the window app but the browse button doesn't seem to work. I don't know where I have made a mistake, please help me

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Gui {
    /** Launch the application. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Gui window = new Gui();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /** Create the application. */
    public Gui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /** Initialize the contents of the frame. */
    private void initialize() {
        GuiJFrame guiJFrame = new GuiJFrame();
        guiJFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class GuiJFrame extends JFrame {

    private JButton btnBrowse;
    private JTextArea   log, filtered_log;

    public GuiJFrame() {
        this.setTitle("TikaExtractorGui");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(panel_2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*
         * BUTTONS *
         */
        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
        panel_1.add(btnBrowse);
        /*
         * Text_Areas*
         */
        JTextArea log = new JTextArea(50, 30);
        panel_2.add(log);
        log.setEditable(false);
        /*
         * LAYOUT *
         */
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(panel_1, FlowLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel_2, FlowLayout.LEFT);

        JScrollPane logScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(log);
        logScrollPane1.setSize(300, 300);
        add(logScrollPane1);

        /*
         * Setting the handlers *
         */
        ActionHandler a_handler = new ActionHandler();
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(a_handler);

    }

    private class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            TikaExtractorInterface ex = new TikaExtractor();
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser();
            String g = null;

            if (event.getSource() == btnBrowse) {
                final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(log);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    if (file.getName().endsWith("pdf")) {
                        file.getPath();
                        if (file != null) {
                            try {
                                g = ex.extractFromFile(parser, file);
                                log.setText(g);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem you are confronted with??

Comment: the Button doesnt work.It wont open the dialog to choose a file.
Seems like it cant "see" the class ActionHandler

Comment: +1 for providing an almost complete SSCE. :)

Comment: Hey!I corrected the code and added the TikaExtractor  class for anyone who wants to give it a glance, since it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
 if(event.getSource() == btnBrowse)
```

should be

```
 if(event.getSource().equals(btnBrowse))
```

You can't use the `==` to identify an equal object in java, you always have to use `equals()` to make sure that two objects are the same.

This:

```
 JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
```

should be

```
 btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
```

You are shadowing your class member variable with a local one so the if clause always comapres against a null value. The btnBrowse is never stored in your class.

Comment: Your answer may be also correct, but the problem remains. The Button doesnt respond when i click it.No event is taking place:(

Comment: In this particular case the comparison return valid result.

Comment: Actually you don'rt even need to check if the event source is your button, because you know that it can only be your button. I compiled your code, the reason is that the private class has a separate copy of btnBrowse, which is null. So you just drop the if() clause and it will work in this case.

Comment: I updated my answer. You must apply both changes to make it work.

Comment: thanks for your concern. Every answer actually worked for me. How can i give correct answer to everyone..hmm  :))))

Comment: can i ask you something.?when you compiled it did you manage to load a pdf file_?

Comment: No, I had to remove the references to some classes, as I didn't know what they were. I stripped it to a small sample, that's why I said "almost an SSCE" as there were only two references missing as far as I recall. :)

Answer (score 5):

I know why it is not working.

Change

```
 /* BUTTONS *
     *         */
    JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
    panel_1.add(btnBrowse);
```

to

```
 /* BUTTONS *
     *         */
    btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
    panel_1.add(btnBrowse);
```

Comment: spot on mate. He declared an instance variable for browse button and then created a new object again in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would say add a System.out.println at the entry of actionPerformed method and check if that is being called indeed.

Also its better to use action commands for each button, so that you don't have to check for equality of event source. Something like this:

```
btnBrowse.setActionCommand("Browse"); //before attaching the listener
```

and then in the actionPerformed

```
String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
if("Browse".equals(actionCommand)) {
   JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
   int retVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
}
```

Comment: well well.. Thank you it worked! Any idea why it opens the file dialog 6 times_?

Comment: yes it is. The dialog is denying to be closed 5 times..The sixth time does the job

Comment: I ran the program that you pasted in your question. I don't see the strange behaviour that you mentioned. The dialog opens only once and close after I select a file and click "Open" or "Cancel" or close it by clicking on "Close (X)" button

Comment: hmm..ok.But can you really open a pdf file in the textArea(=log)??

Comment: I didn't attempt that as I don't have TikaExtractorInterface and PDFParser classes

Comment: oops..sorry..got carried away

    g = ex.extractFromFile(parser, file);
          log.setText(file.getName());

Comment: i changed it to this which doesnt require any of the above, but still doesnt work:               log.setText(file.getName());

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It worked for me, but you have to change this line ` JTextArea log = new JTextArea(50, 30);` to `log = new JTextArea(50, 30);` as the instance variable is being overshadowed.

Answer (score 0):

Browse button should be given as argument for filechooser.

```
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(log);
```

should be,

```
 int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(btnBrowse);
```